# do not selected VagrantFile on vagrant up command PHPStorm

Tags: macos, vagrant, phpstorm

When I use PHPStorm on Mac OSX and I want to 'vagrant up', PHPStorm tell me anytime that selected manually the VagrantFile file for launching this command.

But in Windows OS I never need to selected file for launching vagrant.

How can I skip this step selecting file for launching Vagrant with PHPStorm ? I just want to click (or shortcut) for immediatly launching Vagrant.

**technical info**
PHPStorm version : 2019.2
Mac OSX version : 10.14.6 (Mojave)

**Config PHPStorm for Vagrant**
Vagrant executable : vagrant
instance folder : /Users/xxxx/xxxx/my-project (which contain VagrantFile)
Provider : default
Environment variables : (empty)
Boxes and plugins is OK

Answer (score 3):

See: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29826#focus=streamItem-27-2886011.0-0:

> *In fact, IDE asks for Vagrant **executable** path, not the Vagrantfile. It's a quite old bug on macOS - IDE fails to find executable by itself: [PY-18247](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18247). Specifying the absolute path in settings manually (e.g. /usr/local/bin/vagrant instead of vagrant) should do the trick.*

Answer (score 0):

For all those who want to start or stop vagrant very simply with command, it exist an alternative solution for MacOS users :

---

*The solution is*

1/ **that create a external tools** PHPStorm with each command you want to run with shortcut.

2/ **Assign a shortcut to your new external tools** precedently created. Your external tools command created is sorted into External Tools -> External Tools category into Keymap config.

---

*Example external tools config* (PHPStorm->preferences->Tools->External Tools) :

Name : vagrant up

Description : vagrant up

Program : vagrant (vagrant must to be placed into your PATH OS system)

Arguments : up

Working directory : the directory which contain your vagrantFile file

Advanced Options : are optional

---

*Now You can launch a Start and stop command vagrant without the official command PHPStorm*